# Plot a selected range of co-ordinates using x-aaray

Tags: python-3.x, plot, python-xarray

I am trying to plot from a 3-D data grid. For example:

```
data10.isel(z=76,x=256).plot(ax=ax1)
```

gives the following output:
[image: Plot1]

I would like to plot just the top part of this plot so that it is easier to compare multiple curves. I know we can do it by using:

```
ax1.margins(-0.45,0.09)
```

but each time I am having to guess/trial the numbers in the bracket to zoom into the right position. Is there a way I can set the range of co-ordinates for the data that I want to be displayed on the plot?

Thanks!

Edit: How to add legends when plotting multiple curves?

Edit2: Thank you for your feedback! Here is the code I am using to plot from different arrays:

```
f, ((ax1)) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5,5))
data5.isel(x=127,z=125).plot(xlim=(-25,25))
data10.isel(x=127,z=125).plot(xlim=(-25,25))
data15.isel(x=127,z=125).plot(xlim=(-25,25))
data20.isel(x=127,z=125).plot(xlim=(-25,25))
```

gives the following output:
[image]

Legends do not appear by default.

Edit 3:
Final Q: I am trying to copy selected values from the data array into a list to be written into a text file in a particular format.:

```
data = []
data = data5.isel(x=127,z=125)
```

But this copies the coordinates as well, for example: `data[200]` gives:

```
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(0.)
Coordinates:
    z        float64 25.5
    y        float64 26.7
    x        float64 0.2
```

What would be the right way to do this?
Figured this out: `data[200].data` gives the value stored in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the margins of one of the axis you're plotting, just pass `xlim`/`ylim` to `plot`:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")

xx = ds.sel(lon=200, time=ds.time.values[0], method="nearest").air

xx.plot()
```

gives you

[image]

and to limit the `Latitude` axis on x to `30`-`60`:

```py
xx.plot(xlim=(30,60))
```

[image]

A legend is added by default if you plot multiple lines:

```py
xx = ds.sel(lon=[200,207,220], time=ds.time.values[0], method="nearest").air

# note the slight change in syntax for multiple lines
xx.plot.line(x="lat", xlim=(30,50))
```

[image]

#### Edit:

To plot multiple lines from different datasets, you need to use `matplotlib`:

```py
xx = ds.sel(lon=200, time=ds.time.values[0], method="nearest").air

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xlim = (30,60)
plt.figure()
 
xx.air.plot(xlim=xlim, label="Air")
(xx.air*1.5).plot(xlim=xlim, label="Air*1.5")
(xx.air*2).plot(xlim=xlim, label="Air*2")

# adds legend
plt.legend()
```

[image]

And to access values of your dataset, you can use the `values` property of your `DataArray` (note `air` is the variable in my dataset and will return the underlying `DataArray`):

```py
print(xx.air.values[10:20])

#array([277.29   , 278.4    , 280.     , 282.79   , 284.6    , 286.5    ,
#       287.9    , 290.19998, 293.1    , 293.79   ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks! The data selections works like a charm. However, I am plotting from different data arrays and by default, the legends do not show up. I am updating my post with code and screenshots.

Comment: @MadPhysicist see my edits. Just as a comment, if you have more questions, you should consider posting separate new ones. Editing existing ones should be reserved for clarifying the question and adding more information.